# ASP.NET: when to start worrying about globalisation, localisation? Before, while or at the end?

Tags: asp.net

I've followed a interesting tutorial on how to use Resource.resxfile files to allow the webside to be viewed by users from different cultures.

Now, I'd like to know when to start worrying about globalisation, localisation? Before, while or at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John is absolutely right, if it's not a requirement, don't ever worry about it.

On the flip side, however, I don't think you need to worry about it immediately. For the most part moving strings to resources files covers about 80% of the localization work you'll have to do... and that's pretty easy to do.

Comment: So, you mean I can concentrate on building the application in one language then move strings to the resources files later? In fact, I feel like it might be distracting to think about that now. How about, finishing the application first?

Comment: @Richard77: Yes, that's what I'd recommend. In fact, I've taken that approach on 2 sites that I've had to localize and internationalize and it's worked well for us. Just bear in mind that some strings are harder to resource than others (think string in JS files), and it's not 100% of the work you'll have to do (think of maybe setting language preference in a cookie, etc).

Comment: Just one last thing. Can you provide me with some more specialized material on how to localize a website? Thanks.

Comment: Unless the application isn't particularly complex you should think about the issues before and during construction, it'll save you a headache. I really can't recommend leaving it until the end

Answer (score 4):

Is globalization a requirement of your application? If so, then worry about it immediately.

If it's not a requirement, then don't worry about it at all.

Comment: For what I know, the website to be both in English and in French.

Comment: Then it is better you start using resource files from the start of development.

Comment: You have two languages. Do you have two separate cultures? For instance, a Canadian site would be in French and English (by law, I believe), yet only one currency, date/time and number formats would be used. OTOH, if the site is to be used both by users in the US and in France, then you have different cultures. Which is it?

Comment: The second case. Used in both US and France.

Comment: @Richard: then you have more than resource strings to consider, and you should probably consider it now.

Comment: What else do I need to worry about then? can you provide me with resources that deals with that?

Comment: @Richard: simple: [Google ".net globalization](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net+globalization) and you'll find [ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx).